Safari becomes stuck indefinitely when attempting to load some webpages
Roughly a month ago, I noticed that Safari on Mac started to become stuck indefinitely when loading certain webpages. I'll click on a webpage, the progress bar does gets stuck at roughly 50%, after which I am no longer able to navigate on other open pages or open a new page in a new window or tab. All become stuck while loading. I have to quit Safari by navigating to Safari -> Quit Safari in the  menu bar. If I re-open Safari and navigate to the same webpage, it almost always becomes stuck again. Hence, there are some webpages I simply cannot visit.
I've noticed that this always happens when a webpage uses CloudFare connection verification, and often when a webpage uses ReCapatcha (I cannot make posts on sister site StackOverflow, for instance, seemingly because it attempts to ask me to complete a ReCapatcha before posting). This is not always the case, however.
I've tried:

Restarting my Mac by navigating to Apple -> Restart in the menu bar.
Clearing my history and cache by navigating to History -> Clear History in the menu bar.
Using Erase All Content and Settings in System Settings
Updating to the latest version of macOS.
Turning off Private Relay.
Turning on and off automatic proxy detection.

I have an M2 MacBook Air, 8GB of RAM, and I'm running macOS Sonoma 14.6.1. I have no Safari extensions installed, and this problem persists across different WiFi networks, but not across browsers. This may or may not be related, however before this started occurring I was occasionally getting a "no space left on this device" message of some kind when attempting to open some pages, and also had to quit safari to remedy this. This occurred irrespective of my amount of RAM usage, and whether I had only one webpage open in Safari or several webpages and multiple other applications.
I've tried contacting Apple support, however they had no suggestions beyond what I've already tried. The nearest Apple Store is impractically far away.

The first step is to boot in safe mode and test, to rule in a software conflict. Depending on the results of that test, you may also need to enable the Guest User and test that way. Please update your question with the results.
